# C Program Issue: scanf isn't working properly

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

The program below is supposed to demonstrate using an array of pointers to functions.  Everything works great, except the scanf statements that change the value of num1 and num2 (I have them commented in the code).  If I initialize the variables and have them equaling, say, 2, then when I run the program their value's will be 2 regardless of what I enter in scanf to replace the value.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

// function prototypes
void add      (double, double);
void subtract (double, double);
void multiply (double, double);
void divide   (double, double);

int main(void)
{
    // initialize array of 4 pointers to functions that each take two
    // double arguments and return void.
    void(*f[4])(double, double) = { add, subtract, multiply, divide };

    double num1;   // variable to hold the 1st number
    double num2;   // variable to hold the 2nd number
    size_t choice; // variable to hold the user's choice

    printf("%s", "Which operation would you like to perform on the two numbers?\n");
    printf("%s", "[0] add\n");
    printf("%s", "[1] subtract\n");
    printf("%s", "[2] multiply\n");
    printf("%s", "[3] divide\n");
    printf("%s", "[4] quit\n");
    scanf_s("%u", &choice);

    // process user's choice
    while (choice >= 0 && choice < 4)
    {
        printf("%s", "Enter a number: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &num1); // <--- THIS SCANF_S STATEMENT ISN'T CHANGING NUM1'S VALUE
        printf("%s", "Enter another number: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &num2); // <--- THIS SCANF_S STATEMENT ISN'T CHANGING NUM2'S VALUE

        // invoke function at location choice in array f and pass
        // num1 and num2 as arguments
        (*f[choice])(num1, num2);

        printf("%s", "Which operation would you like to perform on the two numbers?\n");
        printf("%s", "[0] add\n");
        printf("%s", "[1] subtract\n");
        printf("%s", "[2] multiply\n");
        printf("%s", "[3] divide\n");
        printf("%s", "[4] quit\n");
        scanf_s("%u", &choice);
    } // end while loop

    puts("Program execution completed");
} // end main

void add(double a, double b)
{
    printf("%1.2f + %1.2f = %1.2f\n", a, b, a + b);
}

void subtract(double a, double b)
{
    printf("%1.2f - %1.2f = %1.2f\n", a, b, a - b);
}

void multiply(double a, double b)
{
    printf("%1.2f * %1.2f = %1.2f\n", a, b, a * b);
}

void divide(double a, double b)
{
    printf("%1.2f / %1.2f = %1.2f\n", a, b, a / b);
}
```

Comment: Try `%lf` instead of `%f`

Comment: `scanf` works fine.  You're not implementing it properly.

Comment: Whitespace is utilized properly in the program.  When I copied it onto Stack Overflow I had to intend a bunch of stuff to make it show up in the greyed out code section and it ended up screwing up the whitespace.

Comment: Just a point:  'printf("%s", "[0] add\n");' - why would you do this?

Comment: Care to elaborate nhgrif?

Comment: Rob: Because pressing 0 points to the 0 indexed function in the array, which is the add function.

Comment: @AdamSchmidt thats not what he meant. He meant why not just `printf("[0] add\n");` and one reason would be you eventually plan on putting justification in the format specifier. Regardless, Kninnug's comment applied to your source on my machine *works*, so perhaps read it again.

Comment: WhozCraig: Ah, right.  Yea, I realize that it's redundant.  The class I'm taking has an example that this is based off of that has the same format.  Just trying to keep the professor happy. ;)

And thank you for redirecting me to Kninnug's suggestion.  It did work.  Why exactly would %lf work, but %f wouldn't?

Comment: Because `%lf` is the correct format specifier for `double`, and `%f` is not. `%f` is for `float`.

Comment: @Rob: Actually, the proper way to do it would be `printf("%s\n", "[0] add");`. Doing it as `printf("[0] add\n");` is generally not a good idea. The format argument of `printf` is intended to be used for format specifiers specifically. Once you start shoving generic strings into that argument, you are running the risk of creating an unintended "format specifier" (by accidental use of `%`, for example). For this reason is is generally advised to put the generic strings into further arguments of `printf` and just use `%s` in the format.

Comment: ...or... puts("[0] add");

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, use the correct format specifiers.

1) When using `scanf()`, `"%f"` is for `float` and `"%lf"` is for `double`.

```
double num1;
// scanf_s("%f", &num1);
scanf_s("%lf", &num1);
```

2) The use of `"%u"` *may* work given your platform, but `size_t` and `unsigned` are not necessarily the same size.  With C11, (and maybe C99) use the `z` modifier.

```
size_t choice;
// scanf_s("%u", &choice);
scanf_s("%zu", &choice);
```

3) It is always good to check the result from `scanf_s()`.

```
if (1 != scanf_s(...)) {
  ; // handle_error();
}
```